# Calling method from a struct

Tags: c#, struct, colors

I'm convering hsb colour to rgb because im converting a java program to c#. However, in the struct for HSBColor, I can't seem to call the methods once I have made an object, like below:

**HSBColor Struct**

```
public struct HSBColor
        {
    public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
            {
                float r = hsbColor.b;
                float g = hsbColor.b;
                float b = hsbColor.b;
                if (hsbColor.s != 0)
                {
                    float max = hsbColor.b;
                    float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s / 255f;
                    float min = hsbColor.b - dif;

                    float h = hsbColor.h * 360f / 255f;

                    if (h < 60f)
                    {
                        r = max;
                        g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                        b = min;
                    }

                }

       ***I know there are missing brackets here, only using snippets of code***
```

**mandelbrot**

```
 private void mandelbrot() // calculate all points
        {
            HSBColor hsbcolor = new HSBColor();
            hsbcolor.FromHSB(h, 0.8f, b);
        }
```

the "FromHSB" in the **hsbcolor.FromHSB(h, 0.8f, b)**; line is underlined stating the error:

*Error  3   'Fractal.Form1.HSBColor' does not contain a definition for 'hsbColor' and no extension method 'hsbColor' accepting a first argument of type 'Fractal_Assignment.Form1.HSBColor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: `Color result = HSBColor.FromHSB(h, 0.8f, b);` *static* methods want *class* not *instance*

Comment: Thankyou very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
```

This means it's a static function. You access a static function by class name.

```
hsbcolor.FromHSB(h, 0.8f, b);
```

hsbcolor is a variable here. Change this line into

```
Color color = HSBColor.FromHSB(h, 0.8f, b);
```

Comment: `HSBColor` parameter isn't required then

Answer (score 0):

According to your method signature

```
  public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
```

you have to put something like this:

```
  // "static" wants class (i.e. HSBColor) not instance
  // FromHSB wants one HSBColor argument: "new HSBColor(...)"
  Color result = HSBColor.FromHSB(new HSBColor(h, 0.8f, b));
```

a better implementation is to convert `FromHSB` from *static* into *instance* method:

```
  public struct HSBColor {
    // note no "static" here
    public Color ToColor() {
      float r = this.b; // change "hsbColor" into "this "
      float g = this.g; 
      ...
    }
```

so you can put it

```
  Color result = (new HSBColor(h, 0.8f, b)).ToColor();
```